# Calculating spaces between roads from PostGIS database?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geometry

Is it possible to calculate the spaces between the roads using a select statement in a PostGIS/PostgreSQL Database?

I tried using some combinations of the predefined functions as ST_Intersects & ST_Difference but did not succeed yet.

Comment: Could you be more precise? What do you mean by spaces? Areas?

Comment: When you say 'spaces', do you mean a) the closest the roads ever come to each other b) the furthest the roads are away from each other c) some measure of average distance between the two roads or d) the area of the space formed from a polygon composed by having each road as two sides of the polygon and an additional one or two sides to complete it?

Comment: d) the polygons trapped between street network

Comment: Please post the SQL that you have tried, as en edit to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the interpretation of *spaces*, the answer can be found in [How can I create polygons of the area surrounded by roads / lines?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/52014) about creating polygons from areas enclosed by roads.